# Fastest way to loop through Elements in Selenium

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, selenium, web-scraping

I want to speed up a big long "for each" loop
The website I'm scraping is kind of awful and slow but the below code works well, it's also just slow.

```
Set lists = driver.FindElementByCss(wholelist)

Set ops = lists.FindElementsByCss("option")

For Each op In ops

If op.Text = clicktext Then
op.Click
Else
End If

Next op
```

There are 3200 op in ops, it takes about a minute to get the one on the bottom of the list.

This is done in VBA but I think(?) the best approach would be the same across languages.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

I've tried first looping the elements into an array first but that was about double the time.

I'm not sure if there is a simple find() method, but I couldn't find it

Comment: try `FindElementsByXPath` something like `//option[text()="clicktext"]` might work

Comment: Xpath isn't quite right for this website because I would need to know which option[#] I will be looking for (//*[@id="cmbISOClass"]/option[1]). Although I could print all option text and use an index in excel to get the option value. This is a good backup plan, thank you.

Comment: Hey, actually that was the correct solution! I wasn't thinking thinking about it incorrectly when I made my previous comment, sorry! For anyone reading this in the future, the xpath is //*[@id="cmbISOClass"]/option[3156] the way I got away with it in vba was helperstring = "//*[@id=""cmbISOClass""]/option[text()=" & "'" & clicktext & "'" & "]""" then helperstring = left(helperstring, len(helperstring) - 1)  I'm positive there's a better way but it's functional